# Override Highcharts waterfall isSum() value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

for the waterfall chart, is there a way to override the value displayed on the column label if it's set to `isSum()` unfortunately, the values passed per column is rounded off so there would be a discrepancy when compared to our excel data when the last column is set as `isSum()`.

Comment: can you show us what you have done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a data label for each column individually.

```
{
            name: 'Balance',
            isSum: true,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            dataLabels: {
                format: 'my data label'
            }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wjhjjtcz/1/

`formatter` callback might be usefull in this case. You can check if the point is sum and depending on that information change its text - you wouldn't have to define a data label for each isSum manually.

```
dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                    if (this.point.isSum) {
                    return 'is sum';
                }
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / 1000, 0, ',') + 'k';
            },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wjhjjtcz/2/

Comment: thanks! this is what solved my problem, though i modified the code a little bit.